# Access forbidden to folders in /Users/user/ on Monterey

Tags: nginx, permissions, homebrew, macos-monterey

I am trying to setup nginx on an Apple silicon mac with MacOs Monterey.

Nginx has been installed with `brew`

If I edit the config file (`/opt/homebrew/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`) to set a new root directory, it works if I point it at a folder that is not associated with my user folder. For example

```
location / {
    root   /var/www/sites;
    index  index.html index.htm index.php;
}
```

However, if I set root to a folder in my home directory, e.g

```
location / {
    root   /Users/name/sites;
    index  index.html index.htm index.php;
}
```

I get a 403 Forbidden error.

Although this seems to be a common setup, lots of tutorials say to put your various sites in `/User/username/Sites`.

I've tried changing the permissions with `chmod 755 sites` and I've tried changing the owner of the `sites` directory to the root user. However none of these worked. I had similar issue when trying to setup apache.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong with my permissions?
Should nginx (and/or apache) be able to access folders in /Users/user/..?

Answer (score 4):

Add `user username staff;` to `nginx.conf`. That worked for me. Not sure it is good for security.

Comment: nginx ignores it when the service is run as a user process

Answer (score 1):

thanks to vvkatwss

I just want to add some details

`nginx.conf` path is here:

```
/usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

we should edit it and in the line 3 add this line: `user username staff;`
and `username` is your username for example:

```
user alex.sa staff;
```

and after that:

```
sudo nginx -s stop
sudo nginx
```

to restart the nginx

and after that it will work

my configuration in `/usr/local/etc/nginx/servers/myExample.test.conf` is